# What do you call someone who hurts or kills others to feel valued or important?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like someone who will injure or murder another person just to prove that they are important.

Comment: Hi Mary, welcome to EL&U. You may be unaware that a requirement for [tag:single-word-requests] is that you supply a sample sentence to show how the word would be used. You should [edit] your post to add this. For further guidance, see [ask] and take our **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: Sadistic =  Driving pleasure from inflicting pain/suffering on others.

Answer (score 2):

Such a person might be called **sanguinary.**

> marked by eagerness to resort to violence and bloodshed

*"went after the collaborators with a sanguinary fury that drenched the land with blood."*

*G.W.Johnson*

[Vocabulary.com]

Please note that the above word need not **necessarily** imply that the thirst for blood is for "feeling valued or important", though.

Moreover, while the word is mostly used as an adjective,  it can also be used as a noun (Wiktionary, for example, lists the word as noun also.)